# Publish local jars to nexus repository through gradle

Tags: gradle

I have some jar files in my local system which I wanted to publish using Gradle script but I could not find any solution till now.
I am able to publish artifacts which my build generates but I want to publish jars which are there in my local system.
I tried to declare the artifact something like following but it is throwing error:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        artifact projJar

    //This is jar file other than my built file which I want to upload (there are same files more in number to be uploaded):
        artifact 'D:/myworkspace/Test/LocalJar.jar'
        artifact source: projJar, classifier: 'src', extension: 'jar'

    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'user'
            password 'password'
          }
        url "http://IP:Port/repository/RepoName/"
    }
}
```

}

Error msg is:

```
 *What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository'.
  > Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven2'
  > Invalid publication 'mavenJava': multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('jar', 'null').
```

Please guide me with some example how I can publish my local jar files to nexus repository (there are a lot of files there in my local which I want to publish)

Comment: Have you had a look at the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225186/uploading-multiple-existing-jars-to-maven-repository-with-gradle ? Based on the error message, I'd say that you need to remove the `artifact projJar` and `artifact source: projJar, classifier: 'src', extension: 'jar'` definitions.

Comment: Tried on both the things but no help. Firstly, I followed the link, build is running successfully but it is not uploading jars which I define explicitly but only the one which is generated from my build. Secondly, I remove the lines which you asked me to remove but I am getting the same error msg. :-(

Comment: @Dr.jacky No I could not, We were exploring artifactory in parallel that time and decided to go for artifactory than nexus and so I did not come back on this question.